# Making a simple calculator with ATMEGA32

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, atmega, calculator

I try to create a calculator with ATMEGA32 but it did not work correctly! For example it do operations like this (2/1=0),(5*6=12808),(22+88=12746). I know that something is wrong but I cannot find it so I need your help. Many thinks

```
while (1)
  {
  // Fkeypad is a function which read the keypad. Its output is character.
  a=Fkeypad();
    d=(int) a;
// I do not know the number of digits so try to make a counter (i) 
   if(a=='1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9')
   i++;
   switch (i){
   case 1:
   temp1=d; //uint temp1
   break;
   case 2:
   temp1=temp1*10+(d);
   break;
   case 3:
   temp1=temp1*100+(d);
   break;
   case 4:
   temp1=temp1*1000+(d);
   break;
   }
  switch (a){ 
//if user push a sign(*/-+) it means that he try to write the second number so I put the first number in temp2 and save the sign in temp3 for when I need to do operation
  case '*':
  i=0;
  temp2=temp1; //uint temp2
  temp3=a; //char temp3
  break;
  case '+':
  i=0;
  temp2=temp1;
  temp3=a;
  break;
  case '-':
  i=0;
  temp2=temp1;
  temp3=a;
  break;
  case '/':
  i=0;
  temp2=temp1;
  temp3=a;
  break;
  case '=':
 {
 i=0;
  if(temp3== '*')
  calc=temp1*temp2;
  if(temp3=='+')
  calc=temp1+temp2;
  if(temp3== '-')
  calc=temp1-temp2;
  if(temp3=='/')
  calc= temp1/temp2;
  sprintf(f,"%0000d",calc); //uint calc
  lcd_puts(f); // char f[5]
   break;
  }
  case 'c':
  {
  i=0;
  lcd_clear();
break;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It may even help you to find your error(s).

Comment: Ismail, you need to learn about right-recursive productions. I've a page I wrote almost 20 years ago that's still buried on the web [here](http://www.infinitefactors.org/jonk/parsing.html). That will help a little.

Comment: Please don't edit the code to "fix bugs" pointed out in answers. That way, the answers no longer make sense to future readers. I did a rollback of changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with these first few lines.

```
a=Fkeypad();
d=(int) a;
if(a=='1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9')
```

I'm assuming that `Fkeypad()` returns an ASCII character value.  If that's not correct then you've got other problems and the rest of this answer is wrong.

First read about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of `==` and `||`.  The `if` statement that you wrote does not do what you intend because of operator precedence.  Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997820/why-cant-i-check-multiple-conditions-using-only-1-equality-operator-in-c).

The following `if` statement does what you intend.

```
if ((a >= '0') && (a <= '9'))
```

Second, simply casting an ASCII numeric character value to (int) does not convert it to its integer equivalent.  Instead you should subtract ASCII `'0'` from the ASCII numerical character value.

This code will give you the proper integer value `d`.  But you may have additional problems elsewhere in your code.

```
a=Fkeypad();
if ((a >= '0') && (a <= '9')) // Is this a numerical character?
{
    int d = a - '0';          // convert from ASCII to integer
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dear Kkrambo. Thank you for your help. Funny to say that, I used (a-'0') the first time I wrote the code but it did not work so after googling and finding a sample code, I changed it. Anyway, I changed everything as you said and it did not work. Also, I thought it would be ASCII so I checked with ASCII table but I could not get a clue. Again, Thank you so much.

Comment: I do what kkrambo said and also I put the `switch (i)` in `if ((a >= '0') && (a <= '9'))` thank you dear kkrambo